# Please Help Me In Basic4Android

Tags: android, basic4android

I'm learning Basic4Android. I want to use animation when I want to go to another activity. I Paste anim (animation files' folder) in my project folder/objects/res/.

I wrote codes. When I compile my project, anim folder automatically be deleted.
And then my emulator (You Wave) gives an error that there is no animation files.
My codes:

```
Sub Button1_Click
Activity.Finish
StartActivity("Menu")
AnimateLayout.SetAnimation("file3","file4")
End Sub
```

and my animation module codes:

```
'Code module
Sub Process_Globals

End Sub

Sub SetAnimation(InAnimation As String, OutAnimation As String)
Dim r As Reflector
Dim package As String
Dim In, out As Int
package = r.GetStaticField("anywheresoftware.b4a.BA", "packageName")

In = r.GetStaticField(File.DirAssets &"/anim",InAnimation)
out = r.GetStaticField(package & ".R$anim", OutAnimation)
r.Target = r.GetActivity
r.RunMethod4("overridePendingTransition", Array As Object(In, out), Array As 
String("java.lang.int", "java.lang.int"))
End Sub
```

What can I do?

Comment: Provides logs if their is any show that we can help you

Comment: Are you adding your animations in to `app/src/main/res/anim` or `app/src/main/res/animator`?

Comment: Project12\Objects\res\anim                               Project12 is my project's folder

Comment: Set the directory properties to read only

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `anim` folder or `anim` file to "read only" before compiling from basic4android.

I wish you good luck.